# Custom Spell Checker in Swift

Tags: ios, keyboard, spell-checking, swift5, search-suggestion

I am gonna create a custom keyboard app in ios swift.
Could I use my own dictionary file for the spell checking? In other words, by adding text file including some words, is it possible to add suggestion word and spell checking?